# Can I force my Huawei E1550 modem to be usable on another network?

Tags: networking, internet, modem, 3g

I have huawei e1550 3g modem and it is locked to network operator "Idea" while using through windows(which I don't like).

Is it possible to use another network operator on this modem on ubuntu or Is it also locked for ubuntu?

I am able to access internet using it via the default network operator, but not by another operator.Is it my fault or Its also locked on ubuntu? But I have entered the correct settings.

While checking for network locks using ixconn I found the following:-

```
* Test for netlock           

Manufacturer: huawei    
Model: E1550    
Revision: 11.608.13.02.00    
IMEI: 354638041122655    
+GCAP: +CGSM,+FCLASS,+DS

OK    
--- No network locks recognized. ---
```

and it also shows the n/w operators  availabe on doing gprs n/w analysis

on doing AT^CARDLOCK?
i got 3,0,0
which mean that this can't be unlocked

on connecting to internet it keeps searching network and never connects to internet(except default operator)

I need explanation wether if its locked for ubuntu or not?
and if not whats the problem?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by `locked for Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1):

3G sticks are by and large designed only to be used on a particular network operator. When you got it from Idea, only connections with Idea 3G data plan enabled will work. It is not a Ubuntu thing. The problem is that Ubuntu *might* detect the card, but configuring it for use is a different matter.

Comment: I mean ,can I use other n/w simcard on this modem to access internet on ubuntu

Comment: Nope. On an Idea 3g, you can only use a Idea sim, unless the Stick and card are locked somehow.

Comment: but i have upgraded the firmware , which mean its not unlocked  but still can't use another simcard

Answer (score 1):

I think the stick is locked. It is easily possible to unlock the stick with the software for Windows. I have the same which was locked and is now unlocked. But i don't know if it's illegal to describe the way here so it's the best to search for it on google.

Comment: hi geelu,i have already tried  to unlock and upgrade the frimware i tried each and every firmware current firmware version is 11.609.18.00.00 and previous was 11.608...sth  i don't think it remains locked  after firmware upgrade but still while i use this modem with other simcard inserted and try to access its data in wammu or connect to internet it says simcard accessible in case of wammu and in case of internet it never connects